# Loading a DLL many times with WinDLL under Python

Tags: python, windows, dll, ctypes

I am developing a Python application under Windows that drives the Vellemann K8055 card (an I/O card). The manufacturer provided the DLL. Using a Python module, I can drive it with no issues but one. From time to time, because of some electrical interference, the card resets itself, and if I issue a command toward the card I never get an answer. Beside the fact that I need to fix the electrical interference to eliminate the root cause, there is the problem that the card is at a remote site. I can go there only once every 3 or 4 months. Therefore I need a software workaround.

I realized that if I reload the DLL, the connection to the card is re-initialized, allowing me to drive it again. What I am not sure of is whether there are other implications in loading the same DLL many times using the ctypes `WinDLL` function. Does anybody have experience with this?

Comment: `ctypes.WinDLL` calls WinAPI `LoadLibrary`. When `LoadLibrary` is called again for an already loaded DLL, it just increments the DLL's reference count and returns the handle (base address) of the already loaded DLL. It does not reinitialize the DLL and call its entry point for `DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH`. You'll have to provide a complete, minimal example -- because just creating a new `WinDLL` instance should do nothing expect increment the reference count, which is meaningless since ctypes never calls `FreeLibrary` automatically.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I found out the hardware way to overcome the card reset issue, which is far better then workaround it by sw.